# Android - Support Library - no ActionBar Items showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-support-library

i'am currently developing a App which has a ActionBar.

Because i have to support devices up to API 8 i used the support library v7 from google.

Well ... my menu-xml looks like this: (this is only a test activity)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
</menu>
```

And my Code:

```
package standard.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class test extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

The result is, that there are no icons showing. I have the Items only available when i click on the hardware-option-button ob my Galaxy S3.

I have enough space surely.

Comment: Which icon do you mean? the app icon?

Comment: No. I mean the icon from the menu item.

Comment: Oh. I see. There is an old declaration of the item. Here is the new (with icon - but the old problem):    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not solve the proble totally but i think

```
app:showAsAction="never"
```

does not help try changing with "always" or "room" if my memories are good.

Hope it'll help

> **EDIT:** Options available are *"always"* and *"ifRoom"*. Thanks to [ianhanniballake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake)

Comment: The full list of attributes for `showAsAction` can be seen on the [Menu Resource guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) - the options in question are `always` and `ifRoom`